# plotting multiple lines in Power BI graph

Tags: visualization, powerbi

I would like to plot multiple lines on one graph, but I can't do it with simple "line chart".

I have only one dataset, and what I want to do is to use lines to represent different filters.

I included few filters which are the same for all lines, but each line will have a different filter for one column.

So, to be simple: I am using 4 filters for my dataset, and for all lines 3 filters are the same, but the lines are different because 4th filter is unique for each line (example: Column A = "1" for line A; Column A="2" for line B etc.)

Hope I could explain it well enough,

Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: I suspect you'll have to add some test data and some form of expected output, as well as more information about what the filters are doing, for someone to be able to help.

Comment: See a picture below pls